# Visual Studios Tool to build code and call public methods for debugging?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio, debugging

Working with WCF services there is a handy Test Client tool that allows you to build your service and make calls to public methods.  This is extremely helpful during debugging as you can build your code and walk thru it.  I want to know if there is a tool that does something similar for non-WCF projects?

When working in a non-WCF project to be able to walk thru your code I've created a throw away test that calls whatever method I am wanting to debug.  With this there is no Mocking because I am wanting to make real calls to a development system.  This is not a substitute for creating unit test but just a way to jump into a specific Public method and debug.

Another option is to create a throw away app that calls the method I am wanting to debug.

These options work but are not as convenient as the [WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) so my question again is there some tool similar to the WCF Test Client that would work similar for non-WCF projects?

Comment: Writing unit tests for your methods is the simplest way to implement this. As an added bonus you'll be able to quickly detect whether changes to your code have caused unexpected changes in behavior.